# Ruby - Optional argument wrong match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby function with the following signature:

```
def botao_adicionar(model, prefix = "/#{model.name.tableize}", callback = nil)
```

and I want to make it a call without pass the `prefix` argument, so it takes the default from function that I defined above. So I call it this way:

```
botao_adicionar(model=ArrendamentoContrato, callback="bind_unidades_consumidoras()")
```

And it associates the `callback` value to `prefix` variable. I believe it's matching by the order of arguments, but I explicitly called the name of the argument in the function call... that shouldn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your arguments are positional. Meaning that you can't assign them by name.

It seems that you want to use keyword arguments. The correct syntax for them is this:

```
def botao_adicionar(model, prefix: "/#{model.name.tableize}", callback: nil)
```

And then

```
botao_adicionar(ArrendamentoContrato, callback: "bind_unidades_consumidoras()")
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I mean... didn't knew it was syntax error. Thank you!

Comment: @RonanLopes: it's not syntax error. Just inadequate syntax for what you were trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword arguments:

```
def botao_adicionar(model, prefix: "/#{model.name.tableize}", callback: nil)
end
```

Usage:

```
botao_adicionar(ArrendamentoContrato, callback: "bind_unidades_consumidoras()")
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev with `model` it was a typo - thx for noticing :)